# JQuery Conditional Working Incorrectly

Tags: jquery, if-statement, drupal-7, logic

This is a weird one, but probably simple.

I am doing a simple if to check for the lowest number.
I have debug statements and they are showing me that JQuery is returning that 10<2 is true.

Here is the code:

```
        var lowID = 50;

    $('.tip').each(function() {
        console.log('Tip id = ' + this.id);
        if(this.id < lowID){
            console.log(this.id + '<' + lowID);

            lowID = this.id;
            }
        });
```

And here the debugs:

```
"Tip id = 2" lightbox.js:6
"2<50" lightbox.js:8
"Tip id = 3" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 4" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 5" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 6" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 7" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 8" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 9" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 10" lightbox.js:6
"10<2" lightbox.js:8
"Tip id = 11" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 12" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 13" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 14" lightbox.js:6
"Tip id = 15"
```

For some reason whenever it reaches 10 it says that 10 is less than anything

PLEASE HELP me
this might be the weirdest problem ive seen in a while.

Answer (score 2):

this.Id is coming back as a String.  Parse it as an int.

```
var lowID = 50;
var currentId;

$('.tip').each(function() {
    currentId = parseInt(this.id);

    console.log('Tip id = ' + currentId );
    if(currentId  < lowID){
        console.log(currentId + '<' + lowID);

        lowID = currentId;
    }
});
```

--EDIT--
Corrected so int is always used instead of String by assigning currentId = parseInt(this.id)

Comment: Parsing it as an int there is useless, because it is used three times before that....  You should parse it as an int at the start of the scope

Comment: Thank-you @MarshallOfSound.  I fixed the above code.

Comment: currentId will be re-used on each iteration.  Creating it outside of the .each(...) will prevent the variable from being recreated on each iteration.  In this example, it's not a requirement, but in general I find it's beneficial to pay attention to the scope of your variables.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the scope decision merely why setting it to null at all, why not just define it and leave it at that

Comment: Good point.  I accept the edit.  Setting a variable to null on instantiation is a habit carried over from other languages.  Thanks @MarshallOfSound.

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute is a string, and therefore the `<` operator does a bitwise? comparison as opposed to a numerical comparision.

Easy fix is to use `parseInt(i)`

```
var lowID = 50;

$('.tip').each(function() {
    var currentID = parseInt(this.id);
    console.log('Tip id = ' + currentID);
    if(currentID < lowID){
        console.log(currentID + '<' + lowID);
        lowID = currentID;
    }
});
```